# Reader writers issue: getting different output every time

Tags: c, semaphore

I have written simple solution for Reader-Writer's problem using semaphores in C. But I am getting different output after every successful run. What is the exact reason behind this? Here's the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<semaphore.h>
#include<pthread.h>
#include<string.h>

sem_t x,wsem;
int rc;

void *reader(void *);
void *writer(void *);

int svar=0;

int main()
{
    pthread_t w[2],r[3];
    sem_init(&x,0,1);
    sem_init(&wsem,0,1);

    rc=0;

    pthread_create(&w[0],NULL,writer,(void *)0);
    pthread_create(&r[0],NULL,reader,(void *)0);
    pthread_create(&w[1],NULL,writer,(void *)1);
    pthread_create(&r[1],NULL,reader,(void *)1);
    pthread_create(&r[2],NULL,reader,(void *)2);

    pthread_join(r[0],NULL);
    pthread_join(w[0],NULL);
    pthread_join(w[1],NULL);
    pthread_join(r[1],NULL);
    pthread_join(r[2],NULL);

    sem_destroy(&x);
    sem_destroy(&wsem);

    return 0;
}

void *reader(void *arg)
{

        printf("\nReader is executing......");
        sem_wait(&x);
        rc++;
        if (rc == 1)
        sem_wait(&wsem);
        sem_post(&x);
        printf("Reader-%d : value of shared variable : %d\n", (int)arg,svar);
        sem_wait(&x);
        rc--;
        if (rc==0)
            sem_post(&wsem);
        sem_post(&x);

}

void *writer(void *arg)
{

        printf("\nWriter is executing......");
        sem_wait(&wsem);
        svar=svar+5;
        printf("Writer-%d : value of shared variable : %d\n",(int)arg,svar);
        sem_post(&wsem);

}
```

---

```
Output1 : 
Writer is executing......Writer-0 : value of shared variable : 5

Reader is executing......Reader-0 : value of shared variable : 5

Reader is executing......Reader-1 : value of shared variable : 5

Writer is executing......Writer-1 : value of shared variable : 10

Reader is executing......Reader-2 : value of shared variable : 10

Output2: 

Writer is executing......Writer-0 : value of shared variable : 5

Writer is executing......Writer-1 : value of shared variable : 10

Reader is executing......Reader-1 : value of shared variable : 10

Reader is executing......Reader-0 : value of shared variable : 10

Reader is executing......Reader-2 : value of shared variable : 10 

Output3:

Writer is executing......Writer-0 : value of shared variable : 5

Writer is executing......Writer-1 : value of shared variable : 10

Reader is executing......Reader-1 : value of shared variable : 10

Reader is executing......Reader-0 : value of shared variable : 10

Reader is executing......Reader-2 : value of shared variable : 10
```

Comment: please reformat your code - the includes aren't showing up correctly

Comment: @skaffman: Why did you retag this to C++? The question itself says he's using C, and `stdio.h` is a C header, not a C++ header.

Comment: Why would you expect to get the same output?

Comment: @Cody Gray: +1: I was just about to ask the same thing ... skaffman: -1 ;)

Comment: reader 0  has been created before writer 1 , then how come both writers are executing before readers ? please let me know if i am wrong

Comment: @JAY Threads are not selected to be run in the order they are created.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thread execution is non-deterministic.  Just because you've launched the threads in a specific order does not mean they'll execute in that order.  In this case the way you've structured your semaphores and condition variables, means that once the first writer has written, then either one or more writers can write or one or more readers can read, in no particular order.